# xsl:choose - Hardcoded 0's being added to end of XSLT string

Tags: xslt

I am having an issue that I cannot figure out in XLST where there are hardcoded 0's being added to the end of a string that I am not calling for.  I am using a choose element to prompt placement of the string or to otherwise pick three 0's.

Can anyone tell in my code what I am doing wrong?  See below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Export/Record">
        <xsl:if test="DebitAmount!=0 and DebitAmount!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="ChargedCorpLedgerCode" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentLedgerCode" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CategoryJournalNumber" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="PFAM" /><xsl:text>&#0009;0000,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="LOC" /><xsl:text>&#0009;0000,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ACTV" /><xsl:text>&#0009;0000,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CLIENT"/><xsl:text>&#0009;0000000,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="ProjectLedgerCode=null">
           <xsl:value-of select="ProjectLedgerCode" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="ProjectLedgerCode" /><xsl:text>&#0009;000,</xsl:text>
           </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="DebitAmount" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="''" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="CategoryDesc" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
```

my outcome looks like the below where the 000's are adding correctly when the column is blank, but when it is not, it adds the ProjectLedgerCode + 000

[image]

Comment: Seeing the input would be helpful - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This test:

```
<xsl:when test="ProjectLedgerCode=null">
```

will return true if the string-value of `ProjectLedgerCode` is equal to the string-value of a sibling element named `null`.

If you want to test for `ProjectLedgerCode` not having a string-value, use:

```
<xsl:when test="ProjectLedgerCode=''">
```

or:

```
<xsl:when test="not(string(ProjectLedgerCode))">
```

---

In addition, I believe your results are mixed up.

Comment: Both of these returned the same results when testing. @michael.hor257k - basically the goal here is add the projectledgercode on the line if it does exist, if it does not, it places 000 if that helps at all.

Comment: Compare: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuW and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuW/1. -- If you want to test for the **existence** of a node, use: `<xsl:when test="ProjectLedgerCode">`.

Comment: This is very helpful information, however, when adding this, it no longer adds the 000 into empty cells. @michael.hor257k